# How to specify a output folder for ffmpeg

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am using ffmpeg to convert an audio file to .wav format (Rate -16K, 16 bit, Mono). I want to save the converted audio in a folder but I keep getting this error -

Unable to find a suitable output format for

```
'/var/www/html/myproject/public/audio'
/var/www/html/myproject/public/audio: Invalid argument
```

Here is my code:

```
try{
    $audio = "....audio.ogg"
    $output = public_path().'/audio'; //output folder
    exec("ffmpeg -i {$audio} -ab 16 -ar 16000 -ac 1 {$output}");
}catch(Exception $ex){}
```

Please what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think `$output` have to be complete path with output file name

Comment: Getting this error - /var/www/html/myproject/public/audio/test.wav: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by unistalling ffmpeg and installing using `sudo apt install ffmpeg` instead of `snap`